# How do I setup Windows Server 2012 Remote Desktop Services to allow multiple users to connect to multiple servers?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, remote-desktop-services

There are 10 servers setup on a domain that will each need more than 2 users to be able to connect via RDP to manage IIS, apps and other tasks.  I would like to use one or 2 servers for the licensing servers.  Which RDP role services do I need to install on each member server and each licensing server to make them accessible to my users?

Comment: Why not setup **one server with all the remote administration tools**.  There is very little about Windows these days that actually needs to be managed by a local console.  If you don't need more then two users on a single server at once, then you do not have to setup any RDP role services.  Having more then one user performing maintenance at the same time on a single server has always seemed like a recipe for disaster since they may not be coordinating their efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get two free simultaneous "administrative" connections to Windows Server.

If you require more than two simultaneous connections to a Windows server, that server will need Remote Desktop Session Host installed on it.  And some server will need Remote Desktop Licensing installed on it to issue CALs.  Many Remote Desktop Session Hosts can all use the same license server.

Comment: Note that Remote Desktop Licensing is not free - it will cost you money over and above what you have also paid for your server and workstation licensing. (The two connections you get with "Allow remote connections to this computer" are included with the server license and do not cost extra.) Best advice - install the management tools on the administrators' workstations.

Comment: @Ryan Ries - How do I point each computer to the licensing server?

Answer (score -1):

If you're connecting to these servers for the purpose of managing them, and you don't need more than two users to be simultaneously logged in, then you don't need ant RDs roles or services installed.

In Server Manager, enable Remote Desktop by selecting the "Allow remote connections to this computer" option. Done.

Comment: One of the servers will need 15 concurrent users.  Since we will be purchasing user CALs, might as well have the ability to have more than 2 on other servers as well since we are paying for the CALs anyway.

Comment: Installing the RDS role on a server that isn't going to be used as an RDS server just so you can have more than two concurrent administrative sessions doesn't strike me as the right way to go about things.

Comment: some of our servers have lots of websites and other services that are managed by different teams.  Having concurrent access by more than 2 people is a requirement.  My question was the correct way to implement the requirement, not a request on whether or not you think it is a good idea.